# NUnit.Framework.AssertionException : Not all parameters were bound.-Nunit & Moq

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nunit, moq

I have a Asp.net Core WebApi controller action method

```
[HttpPost("v1/file/upload")]
public IActionResult FileUpload([FromForm] UploadRequest uploadRequest)
{
    // Body
}
```

and Unit Test Case

```
[TestCase("POST", "v1/file/upload", nameof(UploadController.FileUpload))]
public void UploadController_When_Given_A_Url_Should_Route_To_Appropriate_Function(string method, string url, string actionName)
{
    ApiRouteAssert<FileApiContainer>.RoutesProperly<UploadController>(method, url, actionName);
}
```

Where `UploadRequest` is a custom Model which is having few properties with `IFormFile`

getting below error in Unit Test, however it works fine when I send request from Postman also unit test passes if I give

```
public IActionResult FileUpload([FromBody] UploadRequest uploadRequest)
```

> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred.   ---->
>   NUnit.Framework.AssertionException :   Not all parameters were bound. 
>   Expected: 0   But was:  1
>
> One or more failures in Multiple Assert block:   1)   Not all
>   parameters were bound.   Expected: 0   But was:  1

Comment: The `NUnit.Framework.AssertionException` comes from code inside a Multiple Assert block, which has to be somewhere in your test code. That's the code you should share with us to get an answer.

Comment: Start from Url Route, Yet to write other Test Methods. This is the only method I have in Test Code File

Comment: I'm talking about hour ApiRoutAssert. That has the code that is giving a failure, so what's in it?

Comment: we have another method which takes 4th parameter as Dictionary<string, object> expectedArguments) and its a dll we are referring. other than this we do not have anything